# FCM registration token not recieved

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented FCM for receiving notification by following [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/first-message?authuser=0) link. But my `didReceiveRegistrationToken` is not called and so I am not getting FCM token. The app delegate conforms to the `FIRMessagingDelegate` protocol `[FIRMessaging messaging].delegate = self;` Still the delegate method is not called. What would be the mistake please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your certificates and upload it necessary file in firebase.I think please double check In your xcode project you enables push Notification Capablities. Try this you may forget this step.

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I missed to upload the APN Auth key to upload. Now it is working fine .Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I have similar problem, everything is configured correctly but I forget to create AppId in the apple developer account.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for me was `Messaging.SharedInstance.AutoInitEnabled = true;`